# Rails/Mysql/SQLite - What's the best idea for building 2- or 3-level menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, tree

I think about the best way, how to create a 2- 3-level menu. My first idea is everything to store to one database table, with the following structure:

```
- id
- item
- level
```

If I create the first-level menu item, so **level** will 0. If I will create the menu item of second level (eg. Contact - phone), so **phone** is the second menu item and the value of **level** will be the ID of Contact.
But now - I don't know, how to print it from database - in the first loop I will print the first level of menu items (with level=0) and then I should to print the second menu items (with level=ID_of_first_menu_item) - exist any elegant way, how to simultaneously print first and second level items (I will build it in Rails)?

And the second way - every level of menu items stored to separate table - but I mean this is not good idea...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you explain me, please, or give some example how to use left join on the same model/table?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set which is basically a tree. suits perfectly for nested navigation

Comment: Thanks Marian for your reply. I am trying to search some tutorial or example around the installation of this plugin, but unfortunately I can't find something useful... Can you give me, please, any help about basic setup of this plugin?